ObjectBox: Storage error "Unknown error" (code 1455) in Flutter windows application
Facing Storage error "Unknown error" (code 1455) on app opening in windows 11.
failed to create store: Could not open database environment; please check options and file system (1455: Unknown error)


Most probably your app does not have the appropriate permissions to write data. This happens in Windows release versions. I suggest using path_provider to get the application path and save the db there. Then use msix package to build a msix package that can be installed on Windows with appropriate permissions. Note that you need a developer credential to make a shareable msix installer. But you can allow it to be trusted on your computer if you need to.
